# Change xclass view extjs 6.2.1 modern

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-modern, extjs6.2

I have a tab panel like this

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    items: [
        {
            title: 'First Tab',
            id: 'firstTab'
            xclass: 'viewClass'

        },
        {
            title: 'Second Tab',
            xclass: ''
        }
    ]});}});
```

in the xclass component there is the path of a class where is defined the view. In the view should be a button, after tap on it, the view should refresh and show another class, for example the view should be defined by 'viewClass2' and not anymore by 'viewClass'
I'm imaging a function triggered on button tap like this:

```
function(): {
    Ext.getCmp('firstTab').xclass = 'viewClass2';
    this.getView().refresh() // but it doesen't exist
}
```

What can i do to change the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can't dynamically change view type.

You can only remove the view and add other one.

Suppose view:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
            id: 'tabId',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'First Tab',
                    id: 'firstTab'
                    xclass: 'viewClass'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

And the function in some one button should be:

```
a = function() {
    Ext.getCmp('tabId').remove(Ext.getCmp('firstTab'));
    Ext.getCmp('tabId').add({'xclass':'viewClass2'})
}
```

Comment: Also,  are you not bypassing the functionality the tab panel is providing by changing the first tab only? rather than changing the tab to the second tab/xclass?

Comment: Bypass which one functionality?

Comment: Changing the component within the tab, rather than switching the tab.

Comment: Your problem was to change view xtype which is impossible. Yes, you can switch visibility to other tab and hide previous (to not shown in header). Previous tab still will be in a DOM.